# Why working directory has not been changed with my script?

Tags: linux, bash

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *_TEx_*.dat;
do
    file1=$i
done

for i in *_TEy_*.dat;
do
    file2=$i
done

echo file1="$file1"
echo file2="$file2"

awk '$0+0 == $0 { printf "%.3f\n", $0 / .05 }' "$file1" > ex65536.dat
awk '$0+0 == $0 { printf "%.3f\n", $0 / .05 }' "$file2" > ey65536.dat

mv *.dat /home/milenko/birrp

mycd() {
    cd /home/milenko/birrp
}

mycd
```

But

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/procmt$ pwd
/home/milenko/procmt
```

What is wrong with my instructions to change the working directory?

Comment: this happens because you are moving to another directory in the subshell that runs the script. Once it finishes, you are back in the main shell, where no `cd` was performed.

Comment: the wd is changed for the sub-shell executing the script, not your interactive shell that spawned the sub-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
...
mycd() {
    cd /home/milenko/birrp
    exec /bin/bash
}

mycd
```

or run your script as below;

```
. ./yourscript.sh
```